# a form 2 buttons 1 dynamic value

Tags: php, html

I have a form with 2 buttons, they have the same dynamic value which is coming from product id.
What I want is when you click on the cart button its sends to cart.php and when you click the wish button it sends to wish.php

But now when I click the cart button it sends to cart.php **and** wish.php and vice versa.

is there any such form, that will do what I want?

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" >                   

<input type="hidden" name="pid"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />  
<input type="hidden" name="pidwish"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />  
<input type="SUBMIT" name="submit"  class="classname"  VALUE="add to cart" onClick="this.form.action='cart.php';this.form.submit()">

<input type="SUBMIT" name="submit"  class="classname"  VALUE="wishlist" onClick="this.form.action='memberSystem/wishes.php';this.form.submit()">

</form>
```

Comment: what you want is you will click a button but two actions must be called. am I right?

Comment: I don't see what your question has to do with Java. Please explain the reason for the Java tag.  You do know that Java is not JavaScript, right?

Comment: Yes ,you r right java nothing to do with question but what i mean 
was  javascript

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as all you're passing is fixed hidden values, what's wrong with:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">                   
  <input type="hidden" name="pid"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />    
  <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit"  class="classname"  VALUE="add to cart">
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="memberSystem/wishes.php">                   
   <input type="hidden" name="pidwish"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />  
  <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit"  class="classname"  VALUE="wishlist">
</form>
```

Comment: problem is when I click on wishlist its even sends to cart.php

Comment: hence why I rewrote the html structure

Comment: Thank you Philip Proplem is fixed for this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try it will work

**JavaScript:**

```
function submitForm(actionPath)
{
  document.form1.action =actionPath;
  document.form1.submit();
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" >                     
  <input type="hidden" name="pid"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />  
  <input type="hidden" name="pidwish"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />   
  <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit"  class="classname" VALUE="add to cart" onClick="submitForm('cart.php')">
  <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit"  class="classname" VALUE="wishlist" onClick="submitForm('memberSystem/wishes.php')">  
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me i am gona try this to when iam home. Thank u

Comment: I fixed my problem Thank you very much guys.I hade a some wrong coding when I try to submit form for wish .IT´s working fine now. This is the best forum I ever hade, gona continue to be a member :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" >                   
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />  
    <input type="hidden" name="pidwish" id="pid_wish" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="button" name="submit"  class="classname"  VALUE="add to cart" onClick="SubmitIt(1);">
    <input type="button" name="submit"  class="classname"  VALUE="wishlist" onClick="SubmitIt(2);">
</form>
```

and use Jquery for form submit.

```
<script>
function SubmitIt(checkVal)
{
    var pid = $("#pid").value;
    var pid_wish = $("#pid_wish").value;
    if(checkVal == 1)
    {
        //submit your form for add cart
    }
    else
    {
        //submit your form for wish
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for helping me, i am working now 
but when i  am at the home i gona try it

Comment: I fixed my problem Thank you very much guys.I hade a some wrong coding when I try to submit form for wish .IT´s working fine now. This is the best forum I ever hade, gona continue to be a member :)